# Gomock SetArg() panicking

Tags: go, go-reflect, gomock

I'm trying to use gomock to mock an interface called `SuccessHandler` to test a function.

The interfaces I have:

```golang
type Item interface {
    SetResults(results string)
}

type SuccessHandler interface {
    HandleSuccess(item Item) error
}
```

And an implementation of `Item`:

```golang
type MyItem struct {
    Results string
}

func (i *MyItem) SetResults(results string) {
    i.Results = results
}
```

Note that since `SetResults` modifies the struct, it is always implemented on a **pointer receiver**.

All I want the mock to do is set the results of `MyItem` when `HandleSuccess()` gets called with `MyItem` as an argument, and modify the value of the argument. Here's what I tried doing for the mock:

```golang
var myItem *MyItem
mockSuccessHandler.EXPECT().HandleSuccess(gomock.Any()).
    Do(func(item Item) error {
        item.SetResults("results")
        myItem = item.(*MyItem)
        return nil
    }).SetArg(0, successItem)
```

This causes a panic with the following:

```
panic: reflect.Set: value of type *MyItem is not assignable to type MyItem [recovered]
    panic: reflect.Set: value of type *MyItem is not assignable to type MyItem
```

Then, I tried changing the variable to just being a struct:

```golang
var myItem MyItem
mockSuccessHandler.EXPECT().HandleSuccess(gomock.Any()).
    Do(func(item Item) error {
        item.SetResults("results")
        myItem = *item.(*MyItem)
        return nil
    }).SetArg(0, successItem)
```

This doesn't panic, but doesn't end up changing the value of `Result`.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The variable `myItem` is not referenced in this code.

Comment: @BurakSerdar good catch, just was named wrong. Fixed